# Conversion of date format in Python

Tags: python, date

I have a date as 05 May, 2015. I want it in 05-May-2015. In another line I also want it in 05052015.How to do this using Python

Comment: Please try to search for an answer yourself before asking a question here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [**How to ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and [what types of questions can be asked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what types should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to read [Python datetime library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)

```
In [28]: from datetime import datetime

In [29]: my_date = '05 May, 2015'

In [30]: custom_date = datetime.strptime(my_date,'%d %B, %Y')

In [34]: first_date_format = custom_date.strftime('%d-%B-%Y')

In [35]: first_date_format
Out[35]: '05-May-2015'

In [36]: second_date_format = custom_date.strftime('%d%m%Y')

In [37]: second_date_format
Out[37]: '05052015'
```

Comment: I have a date '05 May, 1800'. How to convert this in the above formats

Comment: @Esha same logic applies there also.